# Equivalent of RxJava .toList() in Kotlin coroutines flow

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have a situation where I need to observe userIds then use those userIds to observe users. Either userIds or users could change at any time and I want to keep the emitted users up to date. 
Here is an example of the sources of data I have:

```
data class User(val name: String)

fun observeBestUserIds(): Flow<List<String>> {
    return flow {
        emit(listOf("abc", "def"))
        delay(500)
        emit(listOf("123", "234"))
    }
}

fun observeUserForId(userId: String): Flow<User> {
    return flow {
        emit(User("${userId}_name"))
        delay(2000)
        emit(User("${userId}_name_updated"))
    }
}
```

In this scenario I want the emissions to be:

`[User(abc_name), User(def_name)]`, then

`[User(123_name), User(234_name)]`, then

`[User(123_name_updated), User(234_name_updated)]`

I think I can achieve this in RxJava like this:

```
observeBestUserIds.concatMapSingle { ids ->
    Observable.fromIterable(ids)
        .concatMap { id ->
            observeUserForId(id)
        }
        .toList()
}
```

What function would I write to make a flow that emits that?

Comment: Do you want the flow with the 3 listed emissions, or do you want the equivalent of `toList` as in the title? They are quite different questions.

Comment: I just want the latest up to date users at any given time, so the listed emissions is fine.

Comment: Are you missing `[User(abc_name_updated), User(def_name_updated)]` between emissions 2 and 3, or should they not be emitted (and if so why)?

Comment: That could also be emitted, I don't mind, but imagining the delays reflects emissions from the database, I don't really care about that emission because id 123 and 234 should already be emitted and abc and def are out-of-date

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you're looking for `combine`, which gives you an array that you can easily call `toList()` on:

```kotlin
observeBestUserIds().collectLatest { ids ->
    combine(
        ids.map { id -> observeUserForId(id) }
    ) {
        it.toList()
    }.collect {
        println(it)
    } 
}
```

And here's the inner part with more explicit parameter names since you can't see the IDE's type hinting on Stack Overflow:

```kotlin
combine(
    ids.map { id -> observeUserForId(id) }
) { arrayOfUsers: Array<User> ->
    arrayOfUsers.toList()
}.collect { listOfUsers: List<User> ->
    println(listOfUsers)
}
```

Output:

```
[User(name=abc_name), User(name=def_name)]
[User(name=123_name), User(name=234_name)]
[User(name=123_name_updated), User(name=234_name)]
[User(name=123_name_updated), User(name=234_name_updated)]
```

[Live demo](https://pl.kotl.in/yRqfYzmq9) (note that in the demo, all the output appears at once, but this is a limitation of the demo site - the lines appear with the timing you'd expect when the code is run locally)

This avoids the (`abc_name_updated`, `def_name_updated`) discussed in the original question.  However, there's still an intermediate emission with `123_name_updated` and `234_name` because the `123_name_updated` is emitted first and it sends the combined version immediately because they're the latest from each flow.

However, this can be avoided by debouncing the emissions (on my machine, a timeout as small as 1ms works, but I did 20ms to be conservative):

```kotlin
observeBestUserIds().collectLatest { ids ->
    combine(
        ids.map { id -> observeUserForId(id) }
    ) {
        it.toList()
    }.debounce(timeoutMillis = 20).collect {
        println(it)
    }
}
```

which gets you the exact output you wanted:

```
[User(name=abc_name), User(name=def_name)]
[User(name=123_name), User(name=234_name)]
[User(name=123_name_updated), User(name=234_name_updated)]
```

[Live demo](https://pl.kotl.in/6qK0vEWU6)

Comment: Very nice thanks. It seems that Flow is missing an operator like combine, that waits for all flows to emit at least once, rather using the debounce operator which is a little hacky IMO. Zip is available but only for 2 flows, not a list of flows.

Comment: It does in fact wait for all flows to emit at least _once_ - this can be demonstrated by adding `if (userId == "def") delay(250)` to `observeUserForId` - but it doesn't wait for matching emissions each subsequent time like a zip operator would, as you note. Based on the question, I think the current behavior is likely correct: since you're observing the users for changes, you don't want to wait for every user you're watching to update their information at least once before you display any updates, you'd want to show updates as soon as they occur. But zip is probably correct in some cases, too.

Comment: Ah you are right. It is correct without the debounce. Excellent work thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is unfortunatly non trivial with the current state of kotlin Flow, there seem to be important operators missing. But please notice that you are not looking for rxJavas toList(). If you would try to to do it with `toList` and `concatMap` in rxjava you would have to wait till all observabes finish.
This is not what you want.

Unfortunately for you I think there is no way around a custom function.

It would have to aggregate all the results returned by `observeUserForId` for all the ids which you would pass to it. It would also not be a simple windowing function, since in reality it is conceivable that one `observeUserForId` already returned twice and another call still didn't finish. So checking whether you already have the same number of users as you passed ids into your aggregating functions isn't enought, you also have to group by user id.

I'll try to add code later today.

Edit: As promised here is my solution I took the liberty of augmenting the requirements slightly. So the flow will emit every time all userIds have values and an underlying user changes. I think this is more likely what you want since users probably don't change properties in lockstep.

Nevertheless if this is not what you want leave a comment.

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking


data class User(val name: String)

fun observeBestUserIds(): Flow<List<String>> {
    return flow {
        emit(listOf("abc", "def"))
        delay(500)
        emit(listOf("123", "234"))
    }
}

fun observeUserForId(userId: String): Flow<User> {
    return flow {
        emit(User("${userId}_name"))
        delay(2000)
        emit(User("${userId}_name_updated"))
    }
}

inline fun <reified K, V> buildMap(keys: Set<K>, crossinline valueFunc: (K) -> Flow<V>): Flow<Map<K, V>> = flow {
    val keysSize = keys.size
    val valuesMap = HashMap<K, V>(keys.size)
    flowOf(*keys.toTypedArray())
            .flatMapMerge { key -> valueFunc(key).map {v -> Pair(key, v)} }
            .collect { (key, value) ->
                valuesMap[key] = value
                if (valuesMap.keys.size == keysSize) {
                    emit(valuesMap.toMap())
                }
            }
}

fun observeUsersForIds(): Flow<List<User>> {
    return observeBestUserIds().flatMapLatest { ids -> buildMap(ids.toSet(), ::observeUserForId as (String) -> Flow<User>) }
            .map { m -> m.values.toList() }
}


fun main() = runBlocking {
    observeUsersForIds()
        .collect { user ->
            println(user)
        }
}
```

This will return

```
[User(name=def_name), User(name=abc_name)]
[User(name=123_name), User(name=234_name)]
[User(name=123_name_updated), User(name=234_name)]
[User(name=123_name_updated), User(name=234_name_updated)]
```

You can run the code online [here](https://pl.kotl.in/dQVczeJRM)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flatMapConcat](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flat-map-concat.html)

```
val users = observeBestUserIds()
        .flatMapConcat { ids ->
            flowOf(*ids.toTypedArray())
                .map { id ->
                    observeUserForId(id)
                }
        }
        .flattenConcat()
        .toList()
```

or

```
    observeBestUserIds()
        .flatMapConcat { ids ->
            flowOf(*ids.toTypedArray())
                .map { id ->
                    observeUserForId(id)
                }
        }
        .flattenConcat()
        .collect { user ->

        }
```

Comment: This results in a type mismatch. `id` is a list of Strings.

Comment: Updated the response

Comment: Appreciate your help. I think we're getting closer. That however returns a `Flow<Flow<User>>`. What I want is a `Flow<List<User>>` where emissions are as above.

Comment: Updated again, sorry it took this long.

Comment: That's providing a `Flow<User>`. I want emissions of lists of users. It seems so simple but I just can't get it.